# LaTeX source code listing like in professional books

Tags: latex

How should a latex source code listing look like to produce an output like in known books, for example one for the Spring Framework? I've tried with the latex listings package but wasn't able to produce something that looked as nice as the one below. So I'm primarely interested in the formatting instructions to produce something like the sample below (from Manning's [sample chapter](http://www.manning.com/walls3/sample-ch01.pdf) for *Spring in Action*):

[image: From Manning's Spring in Action]

**EDIT**
With the help especially of [Tormod Fjeldskår](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27220/tormod-fjeldsk229r) here's the complete snippet to produce the desired look:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{courier}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily, % Default font
    % numbers=left,              % Location of line numbers
    numberstyle=\tiny,          % Style of line numbers
    % stepnumber=2,              % Margin between line numbers
    numbersep=5pt,              % Margin between line numbers and text
    tabsize=2,                  % Size of tabs
    extendedchars=true,
    breaklines=true,            % Lines will be wrapped
    keywordstyle=\color{red},
    frame=b,
    % keywordstyle=[1]\textbf,
    % keywordstyle=[2]\textbf,
    % keywordstyle=[3]\textbf,
    % keywordstyle=[4]\textbf,   \sqrt{\sqrt{}}
    stringstyle=\color{white}\ttfamily, % Color of strings
    showspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    xleftmargin=17pt,
    framexleftmargin=17pt,
    framexrightmargin=5pt,
    framexbottommargin=4pt,
    % backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
    showstringspaces=false
}
\lstloadlanguages{ % Check documentation for further languages ...
     % [Visual]Basic,
     % Pascal,
     % C,
     % C++,
     % XML,
     % HTML,
     Java
}
% \DeclareCaptionFont{blue}{\color{blue}} 

% \captionsetup[lstlisting]{singlelinecheck=false, labelfont={blue}, textfont={blue}}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox[cmyk]{0.43, 0.35, 0.35,0.01}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\hspace{15pt}#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white, singlelinecheck=false, margin=0pt, font={bf,footnotesize}}
```

Use it with this in your document:

```
\lstinputlisting[label=samplecode, caption=A sample]{sourceCode/HelloWorld.java}
```

Comment: Please be more precise. To me the listing I posted “looks like in professional books” and “looks as nice” as the one you posted.

Comment: Please use the sample posted in form of a screenshot as the result i want to archieve.

Comment: For the sake of completeness you may want to add \usepackage{color} to the tex you posted. Took me a moment before I noticed it was missing.

Comment: Great work! I had to add \usepackage{caption} and \usepackage{graphics} though and it seems to convert single quotes.

Comment: Hi mork where do I have to place the source file? In your example Hello.java

Comment: When I tried to do this, my caption appears at the bottom of the source code, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 196, accepted):

It seems to me that what you really want, is to customize the look of the captions. This is most easily done using the `caption` package. For instructions how to use this package, see [the manual (PDF)](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf). You would probably need to create your own custom caption format, as described in chapter 4 in the manual.

**Edit:** Tested with MikTex:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white}

% This concludes the preamble

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[label=some-code,caption=Some Code]
public void here() {
    goes().the().code()
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image: Preview]

Comment: I would like to redefine the caption format only for things in the \lstinputlisting section (something like myCaption). Have you got any hint how to do that?

Comment: Try /captionsetup[lstlisting]{your options}

Comment: This works great, thank you. Have you got an idea how to realize the gray background behind the caption (like in my initial posts sample)? Cant find anything in the documentation.

Comment: I think \colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\textcolor{white}{text goes here}}} would be somewhere near your initial post sample.

Comment: Wow, if you can say how to apply this to the caption, you're my hero of the day :) \colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\textcolor{white}{text goes here}}}
\lstinputlisting[label=beispielcode,caption=Ein Beispiel]{sourceCode/HelloWorld.java}

Comment: Thats it, thanks a lot :) Have you also any idea how to indent the text inside the caption?

Comment: The margin option, explained in Section 2.4 of the manual, should do the trick.

Comment: No, this also indents the whole surrounding colorbox.

Comment: Ah, of course... Try adding \hspace{1cm} before #1#2#3 in the DeclareCaptionFormat statement.

Comment: This looks nice, but my caption box gets indented (not the text, the box itself). I don't know why, since the listing isn't indented either.

Comment: I included 2 pieces source code in a later chapter (chapter 6), the caption says something like "listing 6.1", "listing 6.2" is there a way to change this caption to say "listing 1" and "listing 2"? Thanks

Comment: @lamba Have you tried setting the numberbychapter key to False? That should cause your listings to be numbered sequentially throughout your document, rather than subnumbered by your chapters.

Comment: I like this snippet, but accents like é in 'caption' make error.

Comment: In case anybody wants to have the listings' background colored as well, you will notice that the caption is wider than the listing. Look here http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/233717/30325 for a solution.

Answer (score 52):

I am happy with the `listings` package:

[image: Listing example]

Here is how I configure it:

```
\lstset{
language=C,
basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\tiny,
frame=tb,
columns=fullflexible,
showstringspaces=false
}
```

I use it like this:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Caption example.,
  label=a_label,
  float=t]
// Insert the code here
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: @lamba: if I remember correctly, it tells Latex to place the it at the top of the page.

Comment: Urgh, listings in proportional font are so massively ugly. (Plus, for cultural reasons, they are hard to read for some (at least many Japanese, maybe also other Asian) people.)

Comment: @mirabilos: yeah, I think I changed it later. It looked OK on this listing but not at all on others with more indentation/nesting.

Answer (score 34):

And please, whatever you do, configure the listings package to use fixed-width font (as in your example; you'll find the option in the documentation). Default setting uses proportional font typeset on a grid, which is, IMHO, incredibly ugly and unreadable, as can be seen from the other answers with pictures. I am personally *very* irritated when I must read some code typeset in a proportional font.

Try setting fixed-width font with this:

```
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}
```

Comment: I personnally use columns=fullflexible with basicstyle=\small\sffamily, as in the example I posted above. The characters aren't vertically aligned, but I think they look better than with \ttfamily. Do you find the sample I posted above ugly?

Comment: Your particular example looks fine. However, I would hate it with nested compound statements where a proper indentation (column alignment) is a *big* help to seeing the extent of a compound statement ({} block).

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but so far all my listings looked good.

Comment: Nested compound statements are a red herring. Since the indentations all consist of spaces, the indentations will line up regardless of the width of other characters.

Answer (score 32):

I wonder why nobody mentioned the [Minted](https://github.com/gpoore/minted) package. It has far better syntax highlighting than the LaTeX listing package. It uses [Pygments](http://pygments.org/).

```
$ pip install Pygments
```

Example in LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{python}
import numpy as np

def incmatrix(genl1,genl2):
    m = len(genl1)
    n = len(genl2)
    M = None #to become the incidence matrix
    VT = np.zeros((n*m,1), int)  #dummy variable

    #compute the bitwise xor matrix
    M1 = bitxormatrix(genl1)
    M2 = np.triu(bitxormatrix(genl2),1) 

    for i in range(m-1):
        for j in range(i+1, m):
            [r,c] = np.where(M2 == M1[i,j])
            for k in range(len(r)):
                VT[(i)*n + r[k]] = 1;
                VT[(i)*n + c[k]] = 1;
                VT[(j)*n + r[k]] = 1;
                VT[(j)*n + c[k]] = 1;

                if M is None:
                    M = np.copy(VT)
                else:
                    M = np.concatenate((M, VT), 1)

                VT = np.zeros((n*m,1), int)

    return M
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Which results in:

[image]

**You need to use the flag `-shell-escape` with the pdflatex command.**

For more information: https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Code_Highlighting_with_minted

Comment: +1. Minted is THE package for typesetting source code in LaTeX. Not only is it easy to use, feature-rich and well documented, but it also has no problems with Unicode characters in source code (unlike `listings`).

Answer (score 21):

Have a try on the `listings` package. Here is an example of what I used some time ago to have a coloured Java listing:

```
\usepackage{listings}

[...]

\lstset{language=Java,captionpos=b,tabsize=3,frame=lines,keywordstyle=\color{blue},commentstyle=\color{darkgreen},stringstyle=\color{red},numbers=left,numberstyle=\tiny,numbersep=5pt,breaklines=true,showstringspaces=false,basicstyle=\footnotesize,emph={label}}

[...]

\begin{lstlisting}
public void here() {
    goes().the().code()
}

[...]

\end{lstlisting}
```

You may want to customize that. There are several references of the listings package. Just google them.

Comment: Thanks. I'am still aware of the listings package, but not able to format like my sample. This is the real question.

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at [`algorithms`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/algorithms/algorithms.pdf) package, especially the `algorithm` environment.

Comment: Thanks. This package seems to be very strong in more theoretical algirthm discussion, i know it from many math books. But i wont emphasize this so much (prerequsites, if, else), i would like to have a formatting like the one above.

Comment: I was only talking about the `algorithm` environment, not `algorithmic`. `algorithm` is a floating container, which looks pretty nice. You can put whatever you'd like inside, even the `listing` mentioned elsethread.

Answer (score 8):

There are several other things you can do, such as selecting new fonts:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
% ... lots of packages e.g. babel, microtype, fontenc, inputenc &c.
\usepackage{color}    % Leave this out if you care about B/W printing, obviously.
\usepackage{upquote}  % Turns curly quotes in verbatim text into straight quotes. 
                      % People who have to copy/paste code from the PDF output 
                      % will love you for this. Or perhaps more accurately: 
                      % They will not hate you/hate you less.
\usepackage{beramono} % Or some other package that provides a fixed width font. q.v.
                      % http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/typewriterfonts.html
\usepackage{listings} 
\lstset {                 % A rudimentary config that shows off some features.
    language=Java,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily, % Without beramono, we'd get cmtt, the teletype font.
    commentstyle=\textit, % cmtt doesn't do italics. It might do slanted text though.
    \keywordstyle=        % Nor does cmtt do bold text.
        \color{blue}\bfseries,
    \tabsize=4            % Or whatever you use in your editor, I suppose.
}
\begin{document} 
\begin{lstlisting}
public final int ourAnswer() { return 42; /* Our final answer */ }
\end{lstlisting} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I believe that in \keywordstyle and \tabsize the backslash should be removed as it wouldn't work this way. Nonetheless very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

For R code I use

```
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
language=R,
basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
commentstyle=\ttfamily\color{gray},
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\ttfamily\color{gray}\footnotesize,
stepnumber=1,
numbersep=5pt,
backgroundcolor=\color{white},
showspaces=false,
showstringspaces=false,
showtabs=false,
frame=single,
tabsize=2,
captionpos=b,
breaklines=true,
breakatwhitespace=false,
title=\lstname,
escapeinside={},
keywordstyle={},
morekeywords={}
}
```

And it looks exactly like this

[image]