# How to write "C++" in LaTeX

Tags: latex

How can I write "C++" in LaTeX so that the output looks nice. For example `C$++$` doesn't look good: the plus signs are too big and there is too much space.

Comment: You could have a look at this other question [LaTeX source code listing like in professional books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/741985/latex-source-code-listing-like-in-professional-books), it looks awesome and works perfectly.

Comment: See also the suggested answers at tex.se.com: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4302/prettiest-way-to-typeset-c

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The standard solution for cases like this is to use verbatim:

```
\verb!C++!
```

Comment: i like this solution but the C looks bad...not like the other text, so i want to append the plusplus sign to a normal C

i try with this but not work:  C \thinspace\verb!++!

Comment: i got it C{}\verb!++!...that looks how i want it.

Comment: But how do I make a definition, that *doesn't* swallow the following space; as this does: \def\cpp{C{}\texttt{++}}

Comment: @user643722 You could include a non-breaking space (`~`) in the definition, but normally you escape the space after a command so LaTeX knows it's an actual space: "\cpp\ is fun". Otherwise it thinks the space is just separating the call to `\cpp` from the rest of the test

Comment: @user643722 The space is swallowed by the parser, so you can't fix that in your definition. The way I've seen and use myself is to enclose the macro inside braces like this "{\cpp} is fun", which frees the parser from depending on the following space to notice that the macro name ended.

Comment: @AlbertoGonzálezPalomo Long time after you've posted this, but generally in LaTeX to handle the space, a better way is to code things like this is as \cpp{} .  There's also xspace, but I think that's overkill.

Answer (score 21):

I've been using the code below to typset a nice looking C++ in my Master-Thesis. The code has been copied verbatim from a [german forum](http://www.informatik-forum.at/showthread.php?33986-C-und-C-in-LaTeX&s=319f025f3afa8711110eb30719b1ad24). You should be able to just copy-paste all the code in a new .tex-document and pick the relevant stuff for you...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%c from texinfo.tex
\def\ifmonospace{\ifdim\fontdimen3\font=0pt }

%c C plus plus
\def\C++{%
\ifmonospace%
    C++%
\else%
    C\kern-.1667em\raise.30ex\hbox{\smaller{++}}%
\fi%
\spacefactor1000 }

%c C sharp
\def\Csharp{%
\ifmonospace%
    C\#%
\else%
    C\kern-.1667em\raise.30ex\hbox{\smaller{\#}}%
\fi%
\spacefactor1000 }

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
{\Huge C++ $\rightarrow$ \C++ \& \Huge C\# $\rightarrow$ \Csharp}\\
\bigskip
\ttfamily
{\Huge C++ $\rightarrow$ \C++ \& \Huge C\# $\rightarrow$ \Csharp}\\
\bigskip
\sffamily
{\Huge C++ $\rightarrow$ \C++ \& \Huge C\# $\rightarrow$ \Csharp}
\end{center}
\section{\C++}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{\Csharp}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks!! the results are nice...one questions that i don't understand in the code...how can you put C++ without math environment or \verb after \Huge?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand your question.
 
The \Huge is just in the code to make it a bit more visible. If you're using the definitions at the beginning of the file, you should be able to just write \C++ anywhere in any environment...

Comment: ok thanks, i was a little confused with the use of the plus sign. I tough that the math environment was indispensable but now i realized that not. xD

Comment: Not bad; looks a bit better to me like this:

  \def\ifmonospace{\ifdim\fontdimen3\font=0pt }
  \def\Cpp{%
  \ifmonospace{C++}\else{C\kern-.13em\raise.65ex\hbox{\textbf{\tiny{++}}}}\fi
  \spacefactor1000 }

Comment: Great answer, although I'd prefer    \textsf{C\kern-.05em\raise.43ex\hbox{\smaller[5]{\textbf{+\kern-.04em+}}}}

Answer (score 15):

You could try and use a typewriter font.

```
\texttt{C++}
```

Answer (score 7):

I've found that the following gives good results:

```
\def\Cplusplus{C\raisebox{0.5ex}{\tiny\textbf{++}}}
```

Comment: I like this result, and it doesn't require adding a whole bunch of extra stuff.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I used loooong time ago:

```
\newcommand*{\Cpp}{C\ensuremath{++}\xspace}
```

to be used like `\Cpp` (needs `xspace` package). But as you said, it is not really beautiful.

Answer (score 3):

This [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4304), for the same question on the tex site, gives what I find to be a good looking way to this.

```
%C++
\newcommand\Cpp{C\nolinebreak[4]\hspace{-.05em}\raisebox{.4ex}{\relsize{-3}{\textbf{++}}}}
%C#
\newcommand\Csh{C\nolinebreak[4]\hspace{-.05em}\raisebox{.4ex}{\relsize{-3}{\textbf{\#}}}
```

Comment: Can't edit because the edit queue is full, but there is a missing closing } on the C# line.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `\cpluspluslogo` command "with the ‘+’ signs properly positioned" in the package [texlogos](https://ctan.org/pkg/texlogos).

An other discussion on *TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange*: [*Prettiest way to typeset “C++” (cplusplus)?*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4302/prettiest-way-to-typeset-c-cplusplus).