# Inserting code in this LaTeX document with indentation

Tags: latex

How do I insert code into a LaTeX document? Is there something like:

```
\begin{code}## Heading ##
...
\end{code}
```

The only thing that I really need is indentation and a fixed width font. Syntax highlighting could be nice although it is definitely not required.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but the answers cover the same ground: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/741985/latex-source-code-listing-like-in-professional-books

Comment: I also have a follow up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408996/insert-code-into-a-latex-doc-without-leading-tabs

Comment: This link can help: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Code_listing

Answer (score 772, accepted):

Use [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/) package.

Simple configuration for LaTeX header (before `\begin{document}`):

```latex
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{frame=tb,
  language=Java,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  numbers=none,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=3
}
```

You can change default language in the middle of document with `\lstset{language=Java}`.

Example of usage in the document:

```latex
\begin{lstlisting}
// Hello.java
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Hello extends JApplet {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("Hello, world!", 65, 95);
    }    
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

Here's the result:

[image: Example image]

Comment: I have a follow up question relating to you code.  Have a look if you get a chance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408996/insert-code-into-a-latex-doc-without-leading-tabs

Comment: Is there a way to reduce space between lines of code ?

Comment: Is it possible to add small text underneath the code snippet, similar to the text written under a figure in Latex?

Comment: @Brian I am not aware of that. Perhaps having the code inside a `figure` could achieve the effect.

Comment: I heard this package is now obsolete!

Comment: If you need to include a JavaScript snippet, check this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89576/125965

Comment: If you want to enlarge the font, consider adding `basicstyle= \large \ttfamily`

Comment: @BrianVar : Here is what you have asked for \begin{lstlisting}[caption={Useless code},label=useless]

Answer (score 232):

You could also use the verbatim environment

```
\begin{verbatim}
your
code
example
\end{verbatim}
```

Comment: There is an issue with using tabs inside the verbatim environment. If tabs are converted to "space" the problem disappears.

Comment: This is good for showing example text file contents (e.g., textual data to be read/processed by a program).

Comment: For two column article, it does not handle the margins well.

Comment: @midtiby, it works fine even with spaces (atleast on overleaf)

Answer (score 132):

Here is how to add inline code:

You can add inline code with `{\tt code }` or `\texttt{ code }`. If you want to format the inline code, then it would be best to make your own command

```
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
```

Also, note that code blocks can be loaded from other files with

```
\lstinputlisting[breaklines]{source.c}
```

`breaklines` isn't required, but I find it useful. Be aware that you'll have to specify `\usepackage{` [listings](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/) `}` for this one.

**Update:** The listings package also includes the `\lstinline` command, which has the same syntax highlighting features as the `\lstlisting` and `\lstinputlisting` commands (see Cloudanger's answer for configuration details). As mentioned in a few other answers, there's also the minted package, which provides the `\mintinline` command. Like `\lstinline`, `\mintinline` provides the same syntax highlighting as a regular minted code block:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
  This is a sentence with \mintinline{python}{def inlineCode(a="ipsum)}
\end{document}
```

Comment: is any better way for inline code which activates keyword colors etc?

Comment: how do you insert spacing/tabs for making it look more readable?

Comment: is it possible to remove space between characters when `mintinline ` is used?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It sounds like a font issue. The minted page on CTAN has thorough documentation for these sorts of things: https://ctan.org/pkg/minted

Answer (score 36):

Specialized packages such as [`minted`](http://ctan.org/pkg/minted), which relies on Pygments to do the formatting, offer various advantages over the `listings` package. To quote from the `minted` manual,

> Pygments provides far superior syntax highlighting compared to conventional packages. For example, listings basically only highlights strings, comments and keywords. Pygments, on the other hand, can be completely customized to highlight any token kind the source language might support. This might include special formatting sequences inside strings, numbers, different kinds of identifiers and exotic constructs such as HTML tags.

Comment: I have tried minted, the documentation is quite straight forward. The default style is quit good.

Comment: This may be an unsatisfactory solution for many users, because of the external call required to Pygmentsic.  In particular, the requirement to call latex with the `-shell-escape` directive is, at best, a minor modification to exisiting build systems, and at worst, incompatible with some users' security preferences.

Answer (score 29):

**Minted**, whether from [GitHub](https://github.com/gpoore/minted) or [CTAN, the Comprehensive TeX Archive Network](https://ctan.org/pkg/minted), works in [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com), TeX Live and MiKTeX.

It requires the installation of the Python package [Pygments](https://pygments.org/); this is explained in the documentation in either source above. Although Pygments brands itself as a Python syntax highlighter, Minted guarantees the coverage of hundreds of other languages.

**Example:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}

\begin{minted}[mathescape, linenos]{python}

# Note: $\pi=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{P_n}{d}$
title = "Hello World"

sum = 0
for i in range(10):
 sum += i

\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Use [Minted](https://github.com/gpoore/minted).

It's a package that facilitates expressive syntax highlighting in LaTeX using the powerful [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) library. The package also provides options to customize the highlighted source code output using [fancyvrb](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb).

It's much more evolved and customizable than any other package!

Comment: However, as already mentioned on a similar answer, `-shell-escape` might suck for some people.

Answer (score 14):

A very simple way if your code is in Python, where I didn't have to install a Python package, is the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}  
\usepackage{pythonhighlight}

\begin{document}

The following is some Python code

\begin{python}
# A comment
x = [5, 7, 10]
y = 0

for num in x:
    y += num
    
print(y)
\end{python}

\end{document}
```

which looks like:
[image]

Unfortunately, this only works for Python.

Comment: The `pythonhilight` package works pretty well out of the box. I used it for a while while trying to get install issues I was having with `pygments` resolved. However, if you want to control: the font size, the syntax highlighting, the background color, the border, whether to include line numbers and where, or have better placement for short code snippets in two column pages, `minted` is a far better option. Also, PyCharm's support for minted is better: it doesn't complain about `_` in a `minted` environment.

Answer (score 7):

Since it wasn't yet mentioned here, it may be worth to add one more option, package [`spverbatim`](https://ctan.org/pkg/spverbatim) (no syntax highlighting):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{spverbatim}

\begin{document}

\begin{spverbatim}
  Your code here
\end{spverbatim}

\end{document}
```

Also, if syntax highlighting is not required, package [`alltt`](https://ctan.org/pkg/alltt):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alltt}

\begin{document}

\begin{alltt}
  Your code here
\end{alltt}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is more or less what I want, but I can't seem to indent with tabs.  How do you indent / is there a similar package that allows for easier indentation?

Comment: @Darokrithia I edited my answer: can you check/confront indentation? :)

Comment: It doesn't seem to work.  I can send you the code I am using, but the formatting is destroyed in comments.   BTW I used a different answer and it worked fine, but I feel like this should still be fixed for future readers.

Answer (score 6):

Use [Pygments](http://pygments.org/languages/) !