# I'm looking for script/program that can convert c code(including colored syntax) to pdf file

Tags: pdf-generation

I have c code and i want it to be on a pdf file for nice viewing, I've looked for scripts/programs(for mac/linux) that can do that but I didn't find any.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Listings package in LaTeX.  There is a thread about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175105/how-to-insert-code-into-a-latex-doc).

A hack is to run [code prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) in an html document on your computer, and then print your html document to pdf from the browser.  Along those lines, you could also run [pygments](http://pygments.org/) and export to HTML, and then to PDF.  Or if you write code with sublimetext, you could use this to export the code directly to HTML: https://github.com/joelpt/sublimetext-print-to-html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the minted package. The use is as simple as listings.

There is a useful tutorial:
https://pt.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Code_Highlighting_with_minted

It is necessary to use -shell-escape when compiling

An advantage that i noticed in the use of minted is the accentuation in the comments, for languages like portuguese. The listings require additional packages and create a series of minor difficulties.