# C Source Code in Latex document

Tags: latex

Can anyone recommend me a good template to include C source code with line numbering
in Latex? For example, taking the classical Hello world program, I would like to make it look as follows:

```
(1)   /* Hello World program */
(2)
(3)   #include<stdio.h>
(4)
(5)   main()
(6)   {
(7)    printf("Hello World");
(8)   }
```

Typicall, I always used the verbatim environment, but I am wondering if there is a better and nicer way to do that.

Thanks so much
Richard

Comment: see tex.stackexchange.com  also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/741985/latex-source-code-listing-like-in-professional-books

Comment: Probably better answer can be get on [TeX and LaTeX stackexchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 15):

As others have said, the [`listings`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf) package will probably do what you want using something like the following:

```
\lstset{
  language=C,                % choose the language of the code
  numbers=left,                   % where to put the line-numbers
  stepnumber=1,                   % the step between two line-numbers.        
  numbersep=5pt,                  % how far the line-numbers are from the code
  backgroundcolor=\color{white},  % choose the background color. You must add \usepackage{color}
  showspaces=false,               % show spaces adding particular underscores
  showstringspaces=false,         % underline spaces within strings
  showtabs=false,                 % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
  tabsize=2,                      % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
  captionpos=b,                   % sets the caption-position to bottom
  breaklines=true,                % sets automatic line breaking
  breakatwhitespace=true,         % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
  title=\lstname,                 % show the filename of files included with \lstinputlisting;
}

\lstinputlisting{HelloWorld.c}
```

A more powerful alternative would be to use the [`minted`](http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf) package, although this will do much more than what you're currently asking, as it uses/requires pygments to be installed on your system so that it can fully tokenize the code you give it.

Answer (score 10):

You might want to have a look at the [`listings` package](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Packages/Listings).  It is very flexible and easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Code listings in LaTeX](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-codelist). You'll find a couple of alternatives there. Some options are:

- [`listings`](https://ctan.org/pkg/listings)
- [`minted`](https://ctan.org/pkg/minted)
- [`lgrind`](https://ctan.org/pkg/lgrind)

Answer (score 0):

Use lgrind package for latex. It converts your code into a .tex file

Answer (score -1):

CWEB had a nice C formatter.